# Change a variable given in a function

Tags: python

I want to make a function that checks if a random number is within a certain value and if it is then reroll the number for that variable.

But I don't know how to set the input variable without calling its name directly.

code:

```
def checkVal(value,max,min):
    if value<max or value>min:
        value=random.randrange((-30/10),(30/10))
        checkVal(value,min,max)
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: What do you expect that `if value<max or value>min` does? (Incidentally, best not to use variable names `min` and `max` as those are names of built-in functions)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask], and try to explain the problem more clearly. What exactly is your **question**? What happens when you try using the code? What is supposed to happen instead, and how is that different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't charge a variable from within a function without using a `global`, however this wouldn't be good practice here. Rather `return` your value.

Also your test would always be True if max>min, you probably meant to swap the conditions (`lower > value  or value > upper`).

```
def checkVal(value, upper, lower):
    if lower > value  or value > upper):
        value = random.randrange((-30/10),(30/10))
        return checkVal(value, upper, lower)
    return value

value = checkVal(value, upper, lower)
```

From an algorithmic point of view, using a recursive function as a loop is also not so good practice. Rather use a `while` loop:

```
def checkVal(value, upper, lower):
    while lower > value  or value > upper:
        value = random.randrange((-30/10),(30/10))
    return value

value = checkVal(value, upper, lower)
```

Finally, you can probably remove the loop entirely by choosing directly the correct bounds:

```
def checkVal(value, upper, lower):
    if lower > value  or value > upper:
        value = random.randrange(max(lower, (-30/10)), min(upper, (30/10)))
    return value

value = checkVal(value, upper, lower)
```